# odoo - web service login using SSL (xml-rpc)

Tags: ssl, web, https, odoo-8, xmlrpclib

I have Odoo 8 installed with Nginx https enabled, How can I connect to the web api securely?, the following code raise an error (Access denied), is this the right way to deal with https connection?

**How connect using python:**

```
url = 'https://mydomain'
ws_common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/common'.format(url))
ws_common.login(dbname, username, pwd)
```

---

**Server Side Error Log:**

```
openerp.service.common: bad login or password from 'sam@sam.com' using database 'db1'
```

**Client side error Log:**

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 800, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 3: 'Access denied.'>
```

**Odoo Configuration:**

```
xmlrpc_port = 9004
host = mydomain
url = https://mydomain
```

Comment: Everything seems to be ok, you are just providing the bad credentials somehow

Comment: Did you solve it? I am right now with that issue